# UICollectionViewのカスタムセルの表示を変更（更新）する方法を知りたい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

カスタムセルが、漢字変換の候補のように、一列に表示されます。

表示ボタンを押し、作成関数InsertTextで文字を入力し、それに合わせた候補を呼び込むために、セルの内容やセル数を更新したいんですが、文字が入力されたら、強制的に作成関数serchTextで、候補を読み直したのち、そのデータでセルを強制的に更新したいんです。

どうすれば、できるでしょうか？

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var Kigou = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

    private var lexicon: UILexicon!
    var myCollectionView : UICollectionView!

    var button11: UIButton!
    var button12: UIButton!
    var fFastBoot = true
    var fPri = CGFloat(20)
    var ifontSize = 18.0
    var RPath = ""
    var sTextNum: Int = 0
    var sTexst: String = "12345"
    var cellNum: Int = 0
    var tText:String = ""
    var sText:String = ""
    var listYomi: [String] = [];
    var listKigou: [String] = [];
    var listDate: [NSDate] = [];
    var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    // Portrait表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var portraitHeight: CGFloat = 190.0
    private var portraitWidth: CGFloat!

    // Landscape表示におけるキーボードの高さ
    private var landscapeHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
    private var landscapeWidth: CGFloat!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    var realmPath: String {
        let containerURL = NSFileManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.AppGroupKigouKeybora")
        return containerURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Dictionary.realm").path!

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pas = realmPath
        print(pas)

        // Perform custom UI setup here
        self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .System)

        self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), forState: .Normal)
        self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
        self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

        let nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        self.view.addConstraints([nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint])

        // CollectionViewのレイアウトを生成.
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        // サイズの設定
        layout.itemSize.height = 10
        layout.itemSize.width = 10
        // Cell一つ一つの大きさ.
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(25, 25)
        // Cellのマージン.
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)
        // セクション毎のヘッダーサイズ.
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0,0)
        // 横スクロール
        layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal  //.Vertical

        // CollectionViewを生成.
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.frame.size.height = 30
        myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 100
        myCollectionView.frame.offset(dx: 2, dy: 2)
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)

        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        print(myCollectionView.delegate)
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        print(myCollectionView.dataSource)

        // Cellに使われるクラスを登録.
        myCollectionView.registerClass(CustomUICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

        myCollectionView.sizeToFit()
        print(myCollectionView.frame)

        view.addSubview(myCollectionView)

        serchText("（")

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 500)
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        var myNativeBoundSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        let myNativeBoundSizeStrW: CGFloat = myNativeBoundSize.width
        let myNativeBoundSizeStrH: CGFloat = myNativeBoundSize.height

        var myWidth = myNativeBoundSize.width
        var myHeight = myNativeBoundSize.height
        // 向きの判定.

        if isLandscape() { // Landscapeだったら、
            let orientation = "Landscape"
            // Landscape用の viewを表示する。
            //print(orientation)

        } else { // Portraitだったら、
            let orientation = "Portrait"
            // Portrait用の viewを表示する。
            //print(orientation)
        }
        var sKishu = "iPad"
        if String(self.view.bounds.size) == "(320.0, 330.0)" {
            // iPhone, iPod touch
            sKishu = "iPhone"
            myWidth = 30
        }else if String(self.view.bounds.size) == "(768.0, 500.0)" {
            myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 764
        }else if String(self.view.bounds.size) == "(1024.0, 500.0)" {
            myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 1020
        }
        print(String(self.view.bounds.size))
        //print(sKishu)

        if CGFloat(myNativeBoundSizeStrH) == CGFloat(1024.0){
            myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(13)
            myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(20)
            //print("iPad縦")
        }else if CGFloat(myNativeBoundSizeStrH) == CGFloat(768.0){
            myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(13)
            myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(11)
            //print("iPad横")
        }else{
            myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(10)
            myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(10)
            //print("Non")
        }

        if fFastBoot == false {
            self.button11.frame = CGRectMake(0,3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2) ,myHeight - CGFloat(6))
            self.button12.frame = CGRectMake(myWidth, 3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2), myHeight - CGFloat(6))
        }else{

            self.button11 = UIButton(type: .System)
            self.button11 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2) ,myHeight - CGFloat(6)))
            self.button11.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            self.button11.addTarget(self, action: "btnUp11:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
            self.button11.addTarget(self, action: "btnDown11:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)

            self.button12 = UIButton(type: .System)
            self.button12 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(myWidth, 3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2), myHeight - CGFloat(6)))
            self.button12.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            self.button12.addTarget(self, action: "btnUp12:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
            self.button12.addTarget(self, action: "btnDown12:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)

        }

        self.button11.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(String(myNativeBoundSizeStrH), comment: "("), forState: .Normal)
        self.button12.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(String(myNativeBoundSizeStrW), comment: ")"), forState: .Normal)
        if fFastBoot == true {

            self.button11.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(ifontSize))
            self.button12.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(ifontSize))

            self.view.addSubview(self.button11)
            self.view.addSubview(self.button12)
            fFastBoot = false
        }
    }

    func btnDown11(sender: UIButton){
        //fDub = false
        self.button11.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    func btnUp11(sender: AnyObject){
        self.button11.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let tText = "）"
        InsertText(tText)
    }

    func InsertText (str: String){
        tText = ""
        sTextNum = sTextNum + 1
        sText = sText + str
        let proxy = textDocumentProxy
        proxy.insertText(str)
        serchText(str)
    }

    private func isWidth() -> CGFloat {
        // 現時点で Landscape表示が適当かどうかを判断する。
        let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        let screenW = self.view.bounds.size.width
        return screenW
    }

    private func isLandscape() -> Bool {
        // 現時点で Landscape表示が適当かどうかを判断する。
        let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        let screenH = screenSize.height
        let screenW = screenSize.width
        let isLandscapeNow =  !(self.view.frame.size.width ==
            screenW * ((screenW < screenH) ? 1 : 0) +
            screenH * ((screenW > screenH) ? 1 : 0))
        return isLandscapeNow
    }

    override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
    }

    override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

        var textColor: UIColor
        let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
        if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
            textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
    }

    // セルの幅自動修正
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        var size: CGSize = listKanji[indexPath.row].sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)])
        print(CGSizeMake(size.width + 20.0, 25))
        return CGSizeMake(size.width + 20.0, 25) //self.flowLayout.itemSize.height)
    }

    /*
    Cellが選択された際に呼び出される
    */
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
        print(listKigou[indexPath.row])
    }

    /*
    Cellの総数を返す
    */
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(cellNum)
        return cellNum
    }

    /*
    Cellに値を設定する
    */
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell : CustomUICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomUICollectionViewCell
        //cell.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row.description
        print(indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = listKigou[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func serchText(inputText: NSString){
        let realm = try! Realm(path: realmPath)
        let results = realm.objects(dic).filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText).sorted("date", ascending: false)
        cellNum = 0
        for result in results {
            print(result.kanji)
            listYomi = listYomi + [result.yomi]
            listKigou = listKigou + [result.kigou]
            listDate = listDate + [result.date]
            cellNum = cellNum + 1
        }
        if cellNum == 0{
        }else{
            cellNum = cellNum - 1
        }
    }
}

class CustomUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell{

    var textLabel : UILabel?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // UILabelを生成.
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height))
        textLabel?.text = "nil"
        textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        // Cellに追加.
        self.contentView.addSubview(textLabel!)
    }

}

class InputCandidate: NSObject {
    var input: String?
}
```

Comment: 更新処理において技術的な課題があるのか、それとも単に更新する方法をご存知でないのかどちらでしょう？後者であれば、まず[リファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)を参照することをお奨めします。（Reloading Contentが該当）

Comment: 調べてもわからなかったんですが、ご指摘いただき、解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。